# Keyboard and PickerView both are visible

Tags: iphone

Im having 3 textfield in one i have implemented a `UIPickerView` and disable the keyboard using `resignFirstResponder` , but when i click on the other, both Keyboard and pickerview are visible .how do i sort this ?

Comment: i think its happen in - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing UITextFields's Delegate method post that method..

Comment: you should hide `UIPickerView`

Comment: when i first click on TextField1 and then directly on TextField2 where i have used [TextField2 resignFirstresponder] so that i can display my pickerView, what happens is my keyboard of TextField1 is still visible along with pickerview. i want only pickerview.

Comment: 2 textfields, one to input text (inputTextField) in it, other one to display contents of pickerView. when i click from 1st textfield(inputTextField) to pickerView TextField , both pickerView and keyboard are visible. but i want only pickerView; i have resigned the pickerViewTextField,

Comment: @prabhanjank89 try my updated answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set every `UITextField`'s Delegate to `self` and then just put this method in your `.m` class.. In this code i just set frame of `yourPickerView` with `500` `y` point instead of that you can Hide the `UIPickerView`..

This code Hides `UIPickerView` with Animation like Keyboard..

**UPDATE:**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       if (textField == TextField1) {
           [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
           [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
           CGRect frame = yourPickerView.frame;
           frame.origin.y = 500;
           yourPickerView.frame = frame;
           [UIView commitAnimations];
           return YES;
        }
       else if (textField == TextField2) {
           [TextField1 resignFirstResponder];
           [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
           [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
           CGRect frame = yourPickerView.frame;
           frame.origin.y = 107;
           yourPickerView.frame = frame;
           [UIView commitAnimations];
           return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: @prabhanjank89 with above code you can hide UIPickerView like system keyboard of UITextField.. :) hope this is helpful to you...

Comment: when i first click on TextField1 and then directly on TextField2 where i have used [TextField2 resignFirstresponder] so that i can display my pickerView, what happens is my keyboard of TextField1 is still visible  along with pickerview. i want only pickerview.

Comment: @prabhanjank89 first tell me what you want to display when user click on textfield2??

Comment: @prabhanjank89 now try my updated code.. just change the y value of pickerview frame like my above code let me know if any problem.. :)

Comment: contents of pickerView will be displayed in textfield2,

Comment: oh then for that in UIPickerView Delegate method just set its title to textfield2 like             textField2.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: this i have done, n every thing works fine, but the TextField Keyboard will hide only on click of 'return', but when control reaches the pickerViewTextfield on direct click; both pickerView and Keyboard are visible, at this point i want to hide keyboard

Comment: @prabhanjank89 i think you not used latest code.. here when your textfield2 is clicked at that time just pickerView appear like keyboard bcoz we return No; for edit text.. you understand??

Comment: the previously appeared keyboard is not dismissing, i see both.

Comment: i checked that mate its working see write you every textfield resignFirstResponder inside that condition its working dude.. but when you again click on the textField1 at that time just set the pickerView frame 500 ... wait i update my answer but its working dude..

Comment: @prabhanjank89 if its not worked now then plzzz check that you give it Delegate to self or not like `textField1.delegate = self;` and also add **UITextFieldDelegate** in .h file also

Comment: Exactly bro ...textFieldShouldBeginEditing,was a big headache, here here`s where experience come into picture....Thank U very much...thanks all...

Comment: Even here if i just say [textField resignFirstResponder]; it works

Comment: yes i know but some times with multiple textfield if you want to hide some otherview with its object name then its very useful you can use textfield otherwise yourTextField1 object to hide its keyboard.. :)

Comment: @prabhanjank89 see bro add UITextFieldDelegate in your .h file after give Delegatew to seld to your whole textfield after use my above code it must worked dude... now its working or not??

Comment: @prabhanjank89 if its helpful to you the accept and upvote the answer please.. :) thanx..

Answer (score 2):

create local instance of `UIPickerView`, and in delegate method of TextFiled `textFieldDidBeginEditing` check for visibility of `UIPickerView`, if it is Visible hide it

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(![_pickerView isHidden])
    {
        [_pickerView setHidden:YES];
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what to show exactly. You can use `[self.view endEditing:YES];` in order to remove the keyboard when necessary, and implement your own method to hide the picker when needed.

Comment: 2 textfields, one to input text (inputTextField) in it, other one to display contents of pickerView. when i click from 1st textfield(inputTextField) to pickerView TextField , both pickerView and keyboard are visible. but i want only pickerView; i have resigned the pickerViewTextField.

Answer (score 1):

Set the picker as the `inputView` for the textfield:

```
myTextField.inputView = self.myPickerView;
```

This way you don't need to handle the displaying of the keyboard/picker at all. It's all done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution : **[inputView Property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)**

```
yourTextField.inputView = self.yourPickerView;
```

Check the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Put this line First when you are going to Display the `PickerView`.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Now after that PickerView Will open & focus will not be on the TextField after writing following line so what you need to do is Put Done Button over Picker & pass the Selected value of Picker to that TextField.

**Try this Code:**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    if(txtVisitDate.isEditing == TRUE)
    {
        if ( [txtPlaceName isFirstResponder] )
        {
            [txtPlaceName resignFirstResponder];
        }
        [aTextField resignFirstResponder];  

        pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];  
        pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; 
        pickerView.hidden = NO;
        pickerView.date = [NSDate date];  

        UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];  
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];  

        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];  

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];  
        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];  

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];  
        [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];  

        [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];  

        [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];  
        [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];  
        [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];  
        [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 475)];  
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: 2 textfields, one to input text (inputTextField) in it, other one to display contents of pickerView. when i click from 1st textfield(inputTextField) to pickerView TextField , both pickerView and keyboard are visible. but i want only pickerView; i have resigned the pickerViewTextField.

Comment: Ok so when you resigned TextField what will happen ? are you able to hide the Keyboard if No than try to put above line.

Comment: the TextField keyboard will hide only on click of 'return', but when control reaches the pickerViewTextfield on direct click  both pickerView and Keyboard are visible

Comment: in - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method put this above line [self.view endEditing:YES]; it'll not Allow keyboard to appear

Comment: i have tried this is not hiding the keyboard, instead i can see both pickerview and keyboard again.

Comment: can you Put the code in the question that you have used for display Picker

Comment: see I have Edited the Answer with the Code i have tried & implemented Successfully. Please try it.